# How do I solve the integral over four spherical harmonics?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I want to solve this integral

```
Integrate[
SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, o, p]*SphericalHarmonicY[l, n, o, p]*
SphericalHarmonicY[l, i, o, p]*SphericalHarmonicY[l, j, o, p], {o, 
0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

but mathematica doesn't give me an answer. I also tried: (simplified in terms of Legendre polynomials and exponential)

```
Integrate[
Integrate[
LegendreP[l, m, o]*LegendreP[l, n, o]*LegendreP[l, i, o]*
LegendreP[l, j, o]*Exp[I*(m - n - i + j)], {o, 0, Pi}], {p, 0, 
2 Pi}]
```

But still no helpful answer, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: The command Table[Integrate[
  SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, o, p]*SphericalHarmonicY[l, n, o, p]*
   SphericalHarmonicY[l, i, o, p]*SphericalHarmonicY[l, j, o, p], {o, 
   0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2 Pi}], {l, -0, 3}, {m, -0, 3}, {n, -0, 3}, {i, -0, 
  3}, {j, -0, 3}] performs {{{{{1/8, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0,
      0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 
     0}, ....}}}}}.

Comment: Shouldn't the integrand have an additional `Sin[o]` term for uniform weighting on the sphere in spherical coordinates? (see e.g. [surface element in spherical coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131735/surface-element-in-spherical-coordinates))

Comment: To get an analytical expression convert a product of 2 spherical harmonics into a sum of spherical harmonics using 3j symbols (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ThreeJSymbol.html). See Gaunt coefficients. Then use this formula second time.